# OBIEE New Calculated Item - Greater than or equal to

Tags: oracle12c, business-intelligence, obiee, comparison-operators

I am trying to create a new calculated item that selects all of the members in the column "Columns.SLA" greater than or equal to 3.

Thank you!

[New Calculated Item Conditional Operator Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhqHn.png)

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I am getting a syntax error when I try to create a new calculated item.  "The syntax of the formula is not valid."

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I am getting a syntax error when I try to create a new calculated item.  "The syntax of the formula is not valid."

Comment: Stupid question: is '3' really a character and not a number?!

Comment: Hi Chris, I have the Data Format in Column Properties set to Number and "Columns"."SLA" is calculated using TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY,"Columns"."Created,"Columns"."Completed date")

Comment: Ok so why are you using a character in the formula then? :)  '3' is a char and not a number

Comment: I tried it as a number as well. In fact, when it is formatted as a measure, it does not appear as an option for a New Calculated Item.

Comment: Have you already tried to do it in the actual column formula? case when SLA >= 3 then '>= 3' else SLA end